# My code seems to be compiling correctly but the GUI isn't appearing (yes, the GUI was designed correctly)

Tags: java, user-interface

I am creating a simple dungeon crawler for an APCS final project basing its GUI of the classic AP gridworld program. I am attempting to create rock walls that are randomized when the program is run. To do this, I extended the rock class. When I run the runner, the code seems to compile correctly, but the GUI doesn't appear (the java icon appears on my dock though).

If you need it, here is the gridworld code:
https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-computer-science-a/classroom-resources/gridworld-case-study

I'm 100% sure the problem resides with my RockWalls class because the driver works fine without adding a wall. The issue may lie with me ignoring the location from the .add() method of ActorWorld (placement of is randomized in the RockWalls constructor).

My current test driver

```
import info.gridworld.actor.ActorWorld;
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ActorWorld world = new ActorWorld();
        world.add(new Location(5, 5), new RockWalls(3, world.getGrid()));
        world.show();
    }
}
```

The RockWalls class

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Rock;
import info.gridworld.grid.Location;
import info.gridworld.grid.Grid;

public class RockWalls extends Rock {

    RockWalls(int numWalls, Grid gameGrid) {

        for (int i = 0; i < numWalls; i++) {

            int length = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;

            int startX = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
            int startY = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;

            boolean isVertical = false;
            if (Math.random() > .5) {
                isVertical = true;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < length && j < 10 && j >= 0; i++) {

                if (isVertical == true && j < 9 && j <= 1
                        && gameGrid.get(new Location(startX + j, startY)) == null
                        && gameGrid.get(new Location(startX - j, startY)) == null) {

                    gameGrid.put(new Location(startX + j, startY), new Rock());
                    gameGrid.put(new Location(startX - j, startY), new Rock());
                } else if (isVertical == false && j < 9 && j <= 1
                        && gameGrid.get(new Location(startX, startY + j)) == null
                        && gameGrid.get(new Location(startX, startY - j)) == null) {

                    gameGrid.put(new Location(startX, startY + j), new Rock());
                    gameGrid.put(new Location(startX, startY - j), new Rock());
                } else {
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "yes, the GUI was designed correctly" -- you can only state this if the GUI/program is *working* correctly. Until then, this assumption must be assumed erroneous until proven otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In your inner for-loop you increment your i variable instead of j which results in an endless loop because your j will never change.

Btw, "j < 9 && j <= 1" is pretty useless.

cu lukas